# Issue with web part check box and ribbon functionality missing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, web-part

I have a strange issue.

My development and production environment were both configured the same way yet I'm having some strange differences when editing the page and adding/deleting web parts.

For instance if I click on a web part while in edit mode and then click on the web part tab up on the ribbon all the choices are grayed out.

The site collection and site features are the same on both environments and both sites were created as team sites.

I've added images to help explain what is missing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've created entire new web applications and still have the same problem. No idea what would cause this and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: I can provide any additional information if needed. Can't seem to find any information about this.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Settings -> Compatibility View Settings. Add the current site and check "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View". Click Close.